# web2py URL rewrite

Tags: python, url-rewriting, web2py

I am playing with web2py url rewrite. The name of application is `py2manager` and I want to make it default in web2py via code:

```
# vim py2manager/routes.py:

routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application='py2manager',
    )
)
```

But after web2py restart I can't access this page http://localhost:8000/user/login (which should be the same as old one http://localhost:8000/py2manager/default/user/login and old one works fine). Ever more I cant find logs for debugging that somehow.

My web2py version is `2.14.6-stable+timestamp.2016.05.09.19.18.48` cloned from git.

How to make correct rewrite with omitting `py2manager/default` path.

P.S. As doc I've used official man http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#URL-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

The default function is `index`, so the router needs more information to distinguish between a request for `/index/user/login` (where `user` and `login` are both args of the `index` function) and `/user/login` (where `login` is an arg of the `user` function). To do this, you must specify the list of functions in the relevant controller:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application='py2manager',
    ),
    py2manager = dict(
        default_controller='default',
        default_function='index',
        functions=dict(
            default=['index', 'user', 'list', 'of', 'other', 'functions']
        )
    )
)
```

Also, if possible, you should use the `URL()` function to generate your URLs, as it will always produce the appropriate URL for a given route based on the configuration of your router.

Answer (score 0):

The routes may need to be reloaded.

If you go to Admin. At the top right corner, next to the Change Admin Password button is a Reload Routes button.